# I can't generate a bib document on texworks

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, auxiliary-files

I cannot generated a bib document and I am growing a bit desperate. I have my references in the bib format, for example:

```
@article{fosfuri2000patent,
  title={Patent protection, imitation and the mode of technology transfer},
  author={Fosfuri, Andrea},
  journal={International Journal of Industrial Organization},
  volume={18},
  number={7},
  pages={1129--1149},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I copy them in a new document and I run latex in order to generate the aux file. But it doesn't run because `\begin{document}` is missing. I can save it as bib, but I can't generate the aux, so I can't run it in bibtex either. Thus even though I have it in my main tex, it doesn't read my references. I have it as:

```
\bibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain
```

Comment: You should have two files: your `.tex` file, and your `.bib` file.  The `.bib` file will contain the bib items like the one you show, and given your example, it should be called `biblio.bib`. Delete your `.aux` files and then  run latex, bibtex, latex, latex to compile the `.tex` document and generate the bibliography (you also need some `\cite{}` commands in your document. Does that work with a simple document?

Comment: `\begin{document} is missing` indicates a problem in your preamble. You should show  the complete error message.

Answer (score 3):

This is surely a duplicate but I can't find it.

Your `.tex` file should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text referencing \cite{fosfuri2000patent}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}% if biblio.bib is the name of your .bib file
\end{document}
```

Then run `pdflatex doc` if your `.tex` file is `doc.tex`.

Then run `bibtex doc`.

Then run `pdflatex doc`.

Then run `pdflatex doc`.

You do not need to copy entries to your `.tex` document. Just use the bib keys (e.g. `fosfuri2000patent`) to refer to the entries you need.

Should you wish to add all entries, even if you don't cite them, you can write

```
\nocite{*}
```